# can the "channel" button for the preview screen be set to a new default value

Tags: video-sequence-editor

When I create a new blend project... the "channel" button for the preview screen is set to channel 1, apparently by default.  Is there a way to make that button default to channel zero?

I ask this because I was trying to do a gamma cross transition and did not realize the viewer channel was set to 1... so even though Blender was doing the cross, fades, wipes, etc... I could not see them happen... and thought something was wrong with Blender... i.e. a bug... or more likely that I... being a noobie... was doing something wrong.
Once I changed the previewer channel button to zero... i could see the transitions happen... and naturally they were in the rendered video.

Please advise as to whether a new default for that channel button can be set in something like user preferences ... and many thanks!!

Comment: Perhaps save a new startup .blend?  I think that would be in the File menu.  So make the change, go back to the 3D view (so that it doesn't always go to the VSE or wherever), and then save.  If that works (unable to test now), let me know and I'll convert it to an answer.

Answer (score 2):

First go to the Video Editing layout:

[image: Switch to video editing]

Now, in my Blender (2.77), this defaults to 0, but find the Channel for the preview here:

[image: Channel number]

Click on the left arrow to change it back to 0.

[image: Switch to 0]

Now here you have an option, you can either go back to the 3D view (Default), or if you are going to be exclusively video editing, leaving it on the Video Editing layout may be useful.

[image: Back to 3D view]

Go to File -> Save Startup File and click it.  You can also use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>U</kbd>.  This can of course be used to save Blender in other states (for instance, having a scene without a cube at the beginning).

[image: Save startup]

Answer (score 0):

You can like Gliderman said when you just change it and save your startup Blend file...

However, you shouldn't do this. As there's a special concept behind Channel 0 as said in the [Introduction](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/introduction.html) to the VSE:

> **Note**
>
> The first channel 0 is unusable as a place to put strips. This is because it is used by the [Sequencer Display](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/sequencer/display_modes.html) to show a composite of all strips above channel 0.

*I think, Mikeycal Meyers explained the concept quite well in his VSE Tutorial Series.*

Comment: This is different, we are not adjusting which channel the clip is on, we are adjusting (and then saving) what channel the viewer is set to.